# Combine pairRDDs by key

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Using pyspark I have grid coordinates `(x,y)` and individual points that lie within each grid square so I have:

```
rdd1 = ((x,y), [point1, point2, point3])
```

I also have an rdd of points that were moved into that grid so:

```
rdd2 = ((x, y), [point4, point5, point6])
```

I want to merge these so that I have:

```
merged_rdd = ((x,y), [point1, point2, point3], [point4, point5, point6])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `join()` and then use `map()` to get the required format.

```
rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(('x', 'y'), ['point1', 'point2', 'point3'])])
rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(('x', 'y'), ['point4', 'point5', 'point6'])])
```

A join will merge the 2 RDDs on the `('x', 'y')` key. But, the lists will be merged in a tuple. SO, we can use a `map()` to get the data in required format, i.e. get the lists out of the tuple.

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).collect()
# [(('x', 'y'), (['point1', 'point2', 'point3'], ['point4', 'point5', 'point6']))]

rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1])).collect()
# [(('x', 'y'), ['point1', 'point2', 'point3'], ['point4', 'point5', 'point6'])]

# can also use this in map()
rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0], *x[1])).collect()
# [(('x', 'y'), ['point1', 'point2', 'point3'], ['point4', 'point5', 'point6'])]
```

Comment: Hi samkart.  I appreciate your response and am sorry that I didn't see it earlier.  This is what I ended up doing although I did have some trouble earlier with the join.  I believe it is because I parallelized the rdd before putting it in pair rdd format so the rdd did not recognize the key.  I unparallelized it and reparallelized it and it fixed it right away so I was able to join.  Thank you again for your help!